# redshift unload : Putting quotes only only character fields and not numeric

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run the unload command on redshift to dump data from a table into a CSV file. This table has character and numeric fields. The character fields may contain a comma (,) , so I need quotes around them. However, I dont need quotes around my numeric columns.

The following command is the closest I have come, but cant seem to get rid of the quotes aroud my numeric data. How can I achieve the desired result?

```
unload ('select * from mytable') to 
's3://mybucket/path/file.csv'
DELIMITER ',' ADDQUOTES
```

This results in data like:

> ```
> "Henry, Jr","23","4.5"
> "Henry, Sr","56","4.2"
> ```

What I would like is :

> ```
> "Henry, Jr",23,4.5 
> "Henry, Sr",56,4.2
> ```

Answer (score 2):

From reading the official documentation, it seems like that's not possible.

I can suggest two potential workarounds:

1) wrap your string columns with quotes in the query, i.e. instead of

`select * from mytable`

have

`select int_col_1, int_col_2, '"'||str_col_1||'"','"'||str_col_2||'"' from mytable`

2) export tab delimited files so the commas in text columns stop being a problem

Comment: Thank you. Yes option 1 seems to be a good workaround. Waiting to see if anyone else can spot an inbuilt option.

Comment: option 2 isn't bad either since you can load tab-delimited files into any db and spreadsheet software supports TSV as well